# How do I fix 32bit dependencies on Ubuntu 14.10 installing pharo?

Tags: installation, x86, 32-bit, pharo, ubuntu-14.10

I'm having trouble installing Pharo on Ubuntu 14.10:

Following those instructions [here](http://pharo.org/gnu-linux-installation#ubuntu-ppa-headless-vm):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pharo/stable
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pharo-vm-core
```

And the last one say there is a dependency problem. `pharo-vm-core : Dépend: pharo-vm-core-i386`

And if I try to install this package, I got other dependencies problems:

```
pharo-vm-core-i386:i386 : 
Dépend: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.16) mais il n'est pas installable
                       Dépend: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) mais il n'est pas installable
                       Dépend: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) mais il n'est pas installable
                       Dépend: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 mais ne sera pas installé ou
                                libgl1:i386
                       Dépend: libssl1.0.0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) mais il n'est pas installable
                       Dépend: libx11-6:i386 mais il n'est pas installable
```

I'm kind of stuck now...

Comment: Am also facing the same issue with Ubuntu server 16.04. Could you find a solution to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be fixed now. That was very close to the release of Pharo 4 and the maintainance team was probably distracted by release issues. For direct help, the [pharo-users mailing list](http://lists.pharo.org/mailman/listinfo/pharo-users_lists.pharo.org) works better